# Facebookt authentification Node.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js, facebook-login

I followed this tutorial

https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-facebook

to handle the facebook login over my website but I have problem with the authentification.

I am getting following error:
[image]

**Node.js route.js**

```
app.get('/login/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {  session: false, scope: [] }));

// handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
app.get('/login/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { session: false, failureRedirect: '/' }),
    function(req, res) {
        console.log('OOOOOOOKKKKKKK!');

        // Successful authentication, redirect home.
        try {
            res.redirect('/');
        } catch (e) {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
```

**auth.js file**

```
'facebookAuth' : {
    'clientID'        : '1721010571523140', // your App ID
    'clientSecret'    : '21769a433182378a103298a6ba91fefe', // your App Secret
    'callbackURL'     : '/login/callback'
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <a href="/login/callback" class="btn btn-info btn-block"> <i class="icon-facebook" ></i> Login mit Facebook </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are your behind corporate proxy ?

Comment: What do you mean with that? How can I find it out?

Comment: Where are your using your Internet Connection like school wifi or Office wifi

Comment: Not sure, but looks as if  `/login/callback` route callback crashes and returns `500` error. Have you checked your server logs? Could you show your route function code?

Comment: ok, see above. I have modified my post